# right Before leaving Vim insert mode

Tags: vim

I need to do someting right before Vim leaves insert mode. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Event `InsertLeave` apparently happens after Vim left the insert mode. I'm using gVim 8.0. Hope this is irrelevent.

```
function! Insert_leave()
    echo mode()
endfunction
autocmd InsertLeave * call Insert_leave()
```

Comment: No, as far as I know there is no trigger for that. maybe you could map the escape key. But i think the best way would be to tell uswhat you try to achieve. There probably is an easier way...

Comment: Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4):

There's no `InsertLeavePre`, but don't worry, switching modes is cheap. Most actions inside Vim involve mode changes, anyway. Why not shortly re-entering insert mode at the same location with `gi`? If you worry about events getting triggered, wrap this with `:noautocmd`, or use an `:autocmd` without `nested`.

Here is an example that inserts `XXX` at the edit location after leaving insert mode:

```
autocmd InsertLeave <buffer> execute "normal! giXXX\<Esc>"
```

Comment: that's exactly what i thougth of, but unless he tells us what he needs it is hard to tell.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo and IngoKarkat, Sorry for the late reply. I am testing a proprietary input method on Windows and try to save its status in Vim insert mode. Since I'm not a Windows guy, I need more time to dig into it. All I know right now is that Windows 8 or later will automatically toggle off the input method, so I have to query the stauts by Python script before vim enters normal mode, which means I might need use `autocmd` to run a Python snippet or something, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the only way to do this, would be mapping the according keys.
Something like:

```
:inoremap <expr> <ESC> yourFunction()."<ESC>"
:inoremap <expr> <C-o> yourFunction()."<C-o>"
:inoremap <expr> <C-c> yourFunction()."<C-c>"
```

yourFunction should return text for that to work properly.

Have a look at `:h map-<expr>` for the information about this. However I am quite unsure, if the `<expr>` mapping will leave insert mode internally or not. Maybe @IngoKarkat can tell you more.

But beware, I only submit this answer because I found it quite interesting and had a lot of fun trying to figure it out. I am not sure if it works but quite sure it is not the best solution for your problem!

Comment: Yes, this should not leave insert mode (you can check with `mode()`). However, mapping `<Esc>` has side effects; it is triggered also when pressing special keys (at least in the terminal).

Comment: Thank you for your statement @IngoKarkat. Could you tell me more about the esc side effects (or point me to an article), I am unfortunaly unable to google a site which does not contain information to avoid the esc key in vim. And don't get me wrong, I absolutly believe you and don't want to save my answer (I already stated, that i do not particulary like it). I just want to learn something I don't know yet.

Comment: If `yourFunction()` is well-behaved, it can work. All I'm saying is that this _can_ cause problems; and I've seen this here and on vim_dev (but also can't find a good example with a quick search). Mapping `<C-c>` is another area that can cause surprises; with a mapping it will fire `InsertLeave` events suddenly.

Comment: @IngoKarkat thank you for your reply, appreciate it. So it sounds like the `InsertLeave` could be fired before the whole `<expr>`-map has finished? Sounds like the event is fired on the keypresses, not the actual leave of the insert-mode.

Comment: No, `<C-c>` by design does _not_ fire `InsertLeave`. But if you map it, it suddenly does, which also is by design. By if you use a mapping like your to "overload" it, it should maintain the original behavior. (I had once reported this as a bug.)

Comment: Another argument in favor of `InsertLeave`: You can have multiple such handlers; for the mapping, the last (plugin) wins.